# Cheap way to capture heart rate data wirelessly with my PC?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

I need to wirelessly capture hearth rate to PC. I was thinking using something like Xiaomi band, but it seems there is no API for that. I just need real time tracking of my hearth rate. And I think using smart watches seems like most convenient solution. But I don't seem to find any viable options.

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Polar H7](https://www.polar.com/uk-en/b2b_products/team_sports/polar_team_indoor_team_sports_coach/accessories/polar_H7_heart_rate_sensor) strap which has Bluetooth Smart and use any application you like for your OS. Polar HR straps are well supported. Here is  screenshot of Heart Beat Monitor from Windows 10 Store. It's not even made by Polar.

[image]

Comment: I'll comment here regarding putting the topic in hold-off : 

"Posts should detail why a simple product search did not work for you."

The requirements are unusual, because heart monitoring in majority of products are mobile oriented, not static - PC connectivity. Manufacturers don't even bother to say their product works with a PC or to supply required software.

@ArtOfCode - please do your research before closing or holding off topics. It's because people like you that Stack Exchange is an unfriendly place for beginners